# Add a CSS file to an aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have an ascx page on which I want to add a link to a css file.

For this I use :

```
<link href="myCSS.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But it doesn't work.

I also try this on the code behind :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink link = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink();
link.Href = "myCSS.css";
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Attributes.Add("title", "Default");
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

And this :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl myCss = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl();
myCss.TagName = "link";
myCss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
myCss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myCss.Attributes.Add("href", ResolveUrl("myCSS.css"));
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(myCss);
```

I put this ascx file on an aspx file which uses a masterpage, maybe the problem is here ?

**EDIT**

The problem is the intellisense see the file (because it show my CSS classes in the file), but it doesn't apply them on my ascx file.

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Where are the page and the myCSS.css file located?

Comment: Is there actually a css file at that location? Run Fiddler2 then load the page. It will show the request for the css file. If it shows a 404 then thats your problem.

Comment: Have you tried using a <link runat='server'> tag and setting the properties on that?

Comment: @Andrei @asawyer The aspx and the css are in the same folder @Tim I tried the `runat="server"` and it doesn't work too

Comment: can you screenshot the folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <link href="../Mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Try This

Comment: Nice nice. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The code you have the minute would assume the CSS file is located in the same directory as your `ascx` file, you should resolve the path so it always comes from the root of the site i.e.

```
<link href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/myCSS.css")%>' rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You could also try just adding the backslash (if they are in the same directory) i.e.

```
<link href="/myCSS.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I thought link tags resolve automatically so there shouldn't be a need to use the ResolveUrl, just the tilda

Comment: The CSS file and the aspx are in the same folder, I tried your solution but it doesn't work too...

Comment: @Pete only if the control is rendered by the server (i.e. `runat="server"`), @Shadam are you using the full path to where the CSS file is located though? My answer is just an example of how to use `ResolveUrl`.